# Most efficient way to convert RDD[Status] to specific json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD[twitter4j.Status] (from TwitterUtils in Spark API) in my Spark streaming app that I want to convert to this json below, where Id would be (status => status.getId().toString) and Text would be (status => status.getText())

I tried a few things, but I'm not happy with the result and was wondering whether there is a really efficient way to do this.

```
{
    "Inputs": [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Text": "hello world"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Text": "hello foo world"
    },
    {
        "Id": "three",
        "Text": "hello my world"
    }]
}
```

Comment: "Efficient" is ambiguous here. Are you trying to save time for humans or the computer?

Comment: " a few things, but I'm not happy with the result " Well, since you won't tell us what you've tried we've no idea what to propose that might make you happy,

Comment: There are lots of tradeoffs here, and focusing on performance is probably counterproductive—it's just not likely to matter much in the context of your program. The fastest way would probably be to write something by hand, but that's miserable. Using a library like Jackson would be less miserable in terms of usage and correctness, and something like circe would not be miserable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created 2 java classes Input and InputsValue and leverage com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2 to convert object to Json string.
Why Java classes and not scala ones? Because gson supports List, where T is a custom object, very easily with Java classes compared to spray-io for example. I might be wrong, but that's what I found so far.

```
public class Input {

    public Input(String id, String text) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public String Id;
    public String Text;
}

public class InputsValue {

    public InputsValue(List<Input> inputs) {
        this.Inputs = inputs;
    }

    public List<Input> Inputs;
}

val i1 = rdd.map(o => new Input(o.getId().toString, o.getText())).collect().toList;
val iv1: InputsValue = new InputsValue(i1)
val inputs = gson.toJson(iv1)
```